# How to set up Sublime language detecting?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I work with different frameworks, so I have several HTMLs in sublime:

- HTML
- HTML(Django)
- HTML(Jinja2)

By default, Sublime opens all html files with HTML(Django). When I work with django it's fine. But in other cases it appears to be a headache. Do you know how to set up default language for the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about the various HTML files, but if you have some way to identify different files, you could try [ApplySyntax](https://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax). If I recall, you can define functions to specify what file to use. I'm not sure what information is passed to the file, but perhaps there is something there to look at project settings or the file path.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can specify syntax on a per project basis.  You may want to look at the [Modelines](https://github.com/SublimeText/Modelines/blob/master/README.rst) package, specifically

> Non-Standard Options
>
> For some common cases, no directly settable option exists (for
>   example, a setting to specify a syntax). For such cases, Sublime
>   Modelines provides non-standard accessors as a stop-gap solution.
>
> x_syntax Packages/Foo/Foo.tmLanguage
>
> Sets the syntax to the specified .tmLanguage file.